# Where was Johann Wilhelm Schweizer from?

Tags: germany, church-records, thuringia

This is from the 1862 marriage entry for Johann Wilhelm Schweizer and Anna Katharina Leinhos, from Creuzburg, Thuringia, Germany.

[image]

As best as I can read it, he is from "Mittirea", but I cannot figure out where that might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are looking at is not a place name:

> Schweizer, Johann Wilhelm, Bürger und Bäckermeister hier, ein Wittwer

- He was a local (“hier” = here)
- He was a widower (“ein Wittwer” = “Witwer” = widower)